# How to handling touchpad?

Tags: java, libgdx, android

- I have a touchpad.  I tried touchpad.getKnobX> 0 and <0 (when swiping the knob left and right) the sprite still displayed but when I put touchpad.getKnobY> 0 and <0 (to swipe knob up and down) the sprite didn't show.  Why is that?

Comment: Can you show us your code in context? And maybe a few screenshots or video so we can understand the symptoms you're observing?

Comment: Using touchpad and move sprite to up and down